# How map data in function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, google-apps-script

I am trying to map data in Google Sheets using the following function:

```
    function convertDataRowsToString() {
    
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();   let data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
    
      data = data.map(row => row.join(";"));  

   console.log(data) }
```

In result 'data' contains information from all column. Finally I want to get data only from column A, column B. column C (First name, Last name, Surname). That is:

```
    [data = \[ 'First name;Last name;Surname',
  'Oliver;Jake;Smith',
  'Jack;Connor;Johnson',
  'Harry;Callum;Williams',
  'Jacob;Jacob;Brown',
  'Charlie;Kyle;Jones',
  'Thomas;Joe;Miller',
  'George;Reece;Davis',
  'Oscar;Rhys;Garcia',
  'James;Charlie;Rodriguez',
  'William;Damian;Wilson']
```

---

I will be grateful for your tips

Comment: What about something like `row.take(3).join(";")`? or `slice(0, 3)` instead of `take()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function convertDataRowsToString() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();   
  let data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  data = data.map(row => row.slice(0,3).join(";"));  
  console.log(data) 
}
```

I say you can just take the first three elements before using the join by using [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?retiredLocale=de).

Answer (score 1):

Use This inside the function:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const sheetData = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

const extractedData = sheetData.map(row => [row[0], row[1], row[2]]);

dataFromCSV = dataFromCSV.concat(extractedData);

console.log(dataFromCSV);
```

Comment: Hi Daeyan, welcome to StackOverflow! Although this is a good answer it would be better if you explain your code as well, especially the few important lines of code like what line 3 and line 4 are doing in this case. Thanks.